# Is there a limit to how many items a list can contain?

Tags: python

So, I have this little bit of code here that I made for fun,

```
import itertools
list = []
for int in itertools.count():
    list.append(int)
       print list[int]
```

Now, all of my friends tell me this will stop working at some point. This led me to believe lists can only contain a finite amount of items. Is this true? If so, what is the limit?

Comment: I think you'll run out of memory faster..

Comment: Internal memory? Hard disk free space? Cloud-based storage? The Internet As A Whole? The number of bits that can be stored in the universe?

Comment: Please see the question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855191/how-big-can-a-python-array-get] and in particular [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15739630/831878).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit, [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) is the maximum number of entries a list can contain:

> The largest positive integer supported by the platform’s `Py_ssize_t` type, and thus the maximum size lists, strings, dicts, and many other containers can have.

Comment: How come the Python 3 documentation for that constant no longer mentions lists, strings or dicts? https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize

Comment: @Boris: The Python 2 and 3 branches each had the value added in separate commits, and the messages merely differed. The Python 2 version was added [when the attribute was backported](https://bugs.python.org/issue2488). The wording in Python 2 was used to differentiate it from `sys.maxint`, a value that's entirely *gone* in Python 3, as [`sys.maxsize` replaced it](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/a37d4c693a024154093b36a612810c3bd72d9254).