# How many items can be used for list based filtering

Tags: django, python-2.7

Let's say I am doing something like

`User.objects.filter(username=[user1, user2, user3])`

What I would want to understand is how large the list with users can be?

E.g. I think it's ok to have 1-100 items there. But what if I will end up adding 10K or even more items?

How the query will work in the case?

Comment: How much memory have you assigned to postgres/django? This query isn't even a valid query, are you looking for a username in that list? that would be horribly inefficient anyway

Comment: this query is not valid. but anyways, do you need this query to be fast? or is it just a background task?

Comment: Well, it should not be slow. In any case, what is the performance impact of having SELECT IN query? And how it depends on the size of the list? (my backend is mysql)

Comment: I'm pretty sure its O(n^2) since you need to check every user against this list, I'd imagine there is a better way for whatever it is you're trying to do but without more information its hard to tell

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855191/how-big-can-a-python-array-get), the maximum elements of a Python list on a 32 bit system is 536,870,912 elements.

How your query will work will depend on your amount of memory, CPU, database used, etc. 
I would suggest to do some benchmarking on the system you're planning to use with sample objects.

Comment: I'd say this is related but not a duplicate, since this question adds a Django specific component.

Comment: Also I don't think the answer above works here, as the question is more django specific. E.g. how many items can be in a list used in query. I believe it should be a bit less comparing to maximum list size for given platfirm