# Can you get the capacity of a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

Lists internally have some sort of capacity that changes depending on how many items we have in it. Is there such a way to access/read the capacity of python's `list`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: So you wanna know the breaking point of a list in Python? Why?

Comment: It's implementation specific.  Some (old, possibly outdated) details of the CPython implementation are in a writeup here: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/

Comment: I might be oversimplifying a bit, but do you mean the length of a given list or the maximum possible length of any list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Big can a Python Array Get?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855191/how-big-can-a-python-array-get)

Comment: @asongtoruin i think he means the physical memory allocated to a list at any one time.

Comment: You could try something like ``sys.getsizeof(theList) - sys.getsizeof([])``, although I'm not 100% sure of what that's measuring.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python, but in .NET, the `List` automatically increases its size when it exceeds its current internally-allocated capacity.  I think the OP wants something like this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. As to why - I want to see when it resizes itself and other fun stuff