# Python - How can you figure out how many items are stored in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can you figure out how many items are stored in a list, or can be? I am assuming the number is unlimited

[10, 20, 30, 40]
['crunchy frog', 'ram bladder', 'lark vomit']

Comment: To check, `len([1,2,3])`

Comment: [And a google search for the second one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855191/how-big-can-a-python-array-get)