# In what situations should you actually use generators in python?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I am trying to get my head around generators and learn about how to use them. I have seen a lot of examples and get that they produce results one at a time rather than outputting them at once like in a regular function. But all the examples I have seen have involved going through a list and printing values that are generated through the function. What if you want to actually create a list?

For example I have seen an example about even numbers which just generates even numbers and prints them out, but what if I want a list of even numbers like this:

```
def even(k):
    for i in range(k):
        if (i%2):
           yield k

even_list = []
for i in even(100):
    even_list.append(i)
```

Does this defeat the purpose of using a generator as it then creates this in an even list. Does this method still save some memory/time?

Or is the below method without using generators just as efficient.

```
def even(k):
    evens_list = []
    for i in range(k):
        if (i%2):
           evens_list.append(i)
    return evens_list
```

In this case in what exact cases are generators useful?

Comment: Typically to save memory (not all elements need to exists at the same time), or time (if you think frequently only the first k elements are necessary), or for things that do not end (like the stream of a webcam).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think the question is more geared towards whether `for i in even(100):` generates the whole sequence in one go anyway

Comment: There are some occasions when constructing a function is much simpler/cleaner via yield than needing to construct the result in the function.

Comment: @roganjosh: the first two points actually apply to `for i in even(100)` as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Does this defeat the purpose of using a generator as it then creates this in an even list. In this case in what exact cases are generators useful?

This is a bit opinion based, but there are some situations where a list might not do the trick (for example because of hardware limitations).

## Saving CPU cycles (time)

Imagine that you have a list of even numbers, and then want to take the sum of the first five numbers. In Python we could do that with an `islice`, like:

```
sumfirst5even = sum(islice(even(100), 5))
```

If we would first generate a list of 100 even numbers (not knowing what we will later do with that list), then we have spent a lot of CPU cycles in the construction of such list, that are wasted.

By using a generator, we can restrict this to only the elements we really need. So we will only `yield` the first five elements. The algorithm will *never* calculate elements larger than 10. Yes, here it is doubful that this will have any (significant) impact. It is even possible that the "*generator protocol*" will require more CPU cycles compared to generating a list, so for small lists, there is no advantage. But now imagine that we used `even(100000)`, then the amount of "useless CPU cycles" we spent on generating an entire list, can be significantly.

## Saving memory

Another potential benefit is saving memory, given we do *not* need all elements of the generator in memory concurrently.

Take for example the following example:

```
for x in even(1000):
    print(x)
```

If `even(..)` constructs a list of `1000` elements, then that means that all these numbers need to be objects in memory concurrently. Depending on the Python interpreter, objects can take significant amount(s) of memory. For example an `int` takes in CPython, 28 bytes of memory. So that means that a list containing 500 such `int`s can take roughly 14 kB of memory (some extra memory for the list). Yes most Python interpreters maintain a "flyweight" pattern to reduce the burden of small ints (these are shared, and so we do *not* create a separate object for each `int` we construct in the process), but still it can easily add up. For an `even(1000000)`, we will need 14 MB of memory.

If we use a generator, than depending on how we *use* the generator, we might save memory. Why? Because once we no longer need the number `123456` (since the `for` loop advances to the next item), the space that object "occupied" can be recycled, and given to an `int` object with value `12348`. So it means that - given the way we use the generator permits this - that the memory usage remains constant, whereas for a list it scales linear. Of course the generator itself also needs to do proper management: if in the generator code, we build up a collection, than the memory will of course increase as well.

In 32-bit systems, this can even result in some problems since Python lists have a [maximum length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/855455/67579). A list can contain at most 536'870'912 elements. Yes that is a huge number, but what if you for example want to generate all permutations of a given list? If we store the permutations in a list, then that means that for a 32-bit system, a list of 13 (or more elements), we will never be able to construct such a list.

## "online" programs

In theoretical computer science, an "online algorithm" is by some researchers defined as an algorithm that receives input gradually, and thus does not knows the entire input in advance.

A practical example can be a webcam, that each second makes an image, and sends it to a Python webserver. We do not know at that moment how a picture that will be captured by the webcam within 24 hours will look like. But we might be interested in detecting a burglar that aims to steal something. In that case a list of frames will thus not contain all images. A generator can however construct an elegant "protocol" where we iteratively fetch an image, detect a burglar, and raise an alarm, like:

```
for frame in from_webcam():
    if contains_burglar(frame):
        send_alarm_email('Maurice Moss')
```

## Infinite generators

We do not need webcams or other hardware to exploit the elegance of generators. Generators can yield an "infinite" sequence. Or `even` generator could for example look like:

```
def even():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 2
```

This is a generator that will *eventually* generate *all* even numbers. If we keep iterating over it, eventually we will yield the number 123'456'789'012'345'678 (although it might take a very long time).

The above can be useful if we want to implement a program that for example keeps yielding even numbers that are palindromes. This could look like:

```
for i in even():
    if is_palindrome(i):
        print(i)
```

We thus can assume that this program will keep working, and do not need to "update" the list of even numbers. In some *pure* functional languages that make lazy programming transparent, programs are written as if you create a list, but in fact it is typically a generator in place.

## "enriched" generators: `range(..)` and friends

In Python a lot of classes do not construct lists when you iterate over them, for example a `range(1000)` object does *not* first construct a list (it does in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x), but not in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)). The `range(..)` object simply *represents* a range. A `range(..)` object is *not* a generator, but it is a class that can generate an iterator object, that works like a generator.

Besides iterating, we can do all kinds of things with a `range(..)` object, that is possible with lists, but *not* in an efficient way.

If we for example want to know whether `1000000000` is an element of `range(400, 10000000000, 2)`, then we can write `1000000000 in range(400, 10000000000, 2)`. Now there is an algorithm in place that will check this *without* generating the range, or constructing a list: it sees if the elements is an `int`, is in the range of the `range(..)` object (so greater than or equal to `400`, and less than `10000000000`), and whether it is yielded (taking the step into account), this does *not* require iterating over it. As a result the membership check can be done instantly.

If we had generated a list, this would mean that Python had to enumerate over every element until it finally can find that element (or reaches the end of the list). For numbers like `1000000000`, this can easily take minutes, hours, maybe days.

We can also "slice" the range object, which yield another `range(..)` object, for example:

```
>>> range(123, 456, 7)[1::4]
range(130, 459, 28)
```

with an algorithm we can thus instantly slice the `range(..)` object into a new `range` object. Slicing a list takes linear time. This can again (for huge lists) take significant time and memory.

Answer (score 4):

Generators are shorter and more readable:

In your example, you have to create an empty list, use `append` and return the resulting list:

```
def even(k):
    evens_list = []
    for i in range(k):
        if i % 2 != 0:
           evens_list.append(i)
    return evens_list
```

The generator just needs `yield`:

```
def even(k):
    for i in range(k):
        if i % 2 != 0:
           yield i
```

And the use is nearly the same, if you need really a list. Instead of

```
event_list = even(100)
```

the line becomes

```
event_list = list(even(100))
```

Answer (score 3):

The generator but in general a lazy semantic offer some advantages:

- You can create infinite list
- You can save a lot of memory because it doesn't keep in memory all the list
- Is often used for expensive IO operations so you can effectively retrieve data only when you really use it

But also some drawbacks:

- Overhead

  - You need to keep in memory the variables of the generator function
  - also risk of memory leak
- Every time you want to reuse the elements in a collection it must be regenerated

Comment: In my example above it does keep the list of evens in memory. So I guess my question was is the generator method any better than the original method above?

Comment: Depends by two factors: the size of the list and the times you use this list. For a list of 100 elements i think there is no space problem. So the last factor is the times you use this even numbers list, if you use once you can use the generator otherwise i suggest you the list

Comment: I don't know if you know but there are two shorter way to generate the even numbers: `filter(lambda el: el % 2 == 1, range(100))` is a generator or the "generator comprehension" `(el for el in range(100) if el % 2 == 1)` is also a generator

Comment: so if my list was for 1000000000 elements then my generator method would be more efficient? I guess the thing im struggling to understand is that both methods involve appending values to a list, so what makes the generator one more efficient after i've added all the values to a list anyways...

Comment: It's not more efficient but in a lot of computer you can't keep 1000000000 elements together in memory so you are forced to use a generator to process this sequence of data